# Smaller strings from a "string"

Tags: python, python-2.7

i have a string

```
str = '788399902432345678901234567890'
```

currently,

```
str[1] = 7
str[2] = 8
```

and so on

I need to rearrange such that

```
str[1] = 7883
str[2] = 9990
```

and so on..

I tried this

```
n = 4
listo = strq
split_list = [listo[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(listo), n)]
```

But this is just splitting the string and not essentially creating small strings

Pls help me with this!

Comment: What do you expect the output to be then? `split_list[0]` will be the first group of 4, etc.... shadowing the builtin `str` is not a good idea either - call it `text` or `data` or something...

Comment: You write `str[1]=7`. But in python indexes start at **0**, so you'd better write `str[0]=7` ...

Answer (score 0):

This should be fine, isn't it? I changed the variable name from str to val as str is a keyword and it should be avoided using as a variable name.

```
>>> val='788399902432345678901234567890'
>>> n = 4
>>> val= [val[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(val), n)]
>>> val[0]
'7883'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the output is exactly what you want?

How should it be different?

```
strq = '788399902432345678901234567890'
n = 4
listo = strq
split_list = [listo[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(listo), n)]

['7883', '9990', '2432', '3456', '7890', '1234', '5678', '90']

split_list[0] = '7883'
split_list[1] = '9990'
```

etc